# How do I check the exposure of my machine to the internet?

Tags: webapp-rec, security

My ISP just sent me over a box ("modem") and now I am online. I am afraid of beeing exposed directly to the internet.

How do I check to which level my machine is accessible from the internet?

Comment: I believe this is on topic because it is looking for a web application to accomplish a task, and there is a clear and great one to use, as already provided in the answers.

Comment: I don't understand why it was closed.  Surely a web-based firewall test is a web application.

Comment: It's not offtopic, it just needs another title like: "Web App to check my machine exposure to the internet"

Comment: Questions asking for web app recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Now it's more a Security question

Comment: feel free to move it to a different site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try ['Shields Up' by GRC](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)